# React - Provide Global Singleton From Composition Root

Tags: reactjs, singleton

To start off, I have been working with React now for three months and the application I am building is testable, performant, etc... Nothing wrong. My experience pre-React is from the Angular world and what is considered a best practice there is not normally in react and vice-a-versa... I don't think what I am doing is wrong for the application I am building also don't want to miss anything big.

To make a long story short, inside of my App.tsx (using TypeScript) file I am creating a new instance of a singleton service and exporting it as a named export. For example, my app component looks something like:

```
import * as React from 'react'
... axios import here

import { HttpService } from './core/http.service';
import { Spinner } from './shared/spinner';

const axiosInstance = Axios.create({config here});
const httpService = new HttpService(axiosInstance);

class App extends React.Component {

  props: any;
  state: any;

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return(<App Root Component Here...>)
  }
}

export { httpService };
export default App;
```

Imagine a component somewhere in the app that needs to use my singleton service. For the purposes of my question, I will call the component Home (home/Home.tsx).

```
import * as React from 'react'

import { httpService } from '../App';

class Home extends React.Component {

  props: HomeProps;
  state: HomeState;

  constructor(props: HomeProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      myData: []
    }

    this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  // Using httpService here.
  loadData() {
    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    httpService.get('/api/somedataurl').then((response) => {
      const { data } = response;
      this.setState({myData: data});
    }).then(() => {
      this.setState({isLoading: false});
    });
  }

  myDataList() {
    return (<ul>...{map of this.state.myData}</ul>)
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.isLoading ? (<Spinner>) : this.myDataList();
  }
}

export default Home;
```

I decided to use this implementation because I know that I can always rely on the App component to be available and there are no plans for server-side rendering.

As a simple solution, is there anything seriously flawed with providing my singleton service as a named export and importing into other components as needed?

Comment: I think i did not understood your question properly. are you asking about best practices ???

Comment: There is nothing wrong with exporting the Singleton as a named export. The only thing better that you can do is to create an export the httpService in a separate file  instead of App.js

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Yes, question is related to best practices. I thought about the separate file approach as it would be cleaner, but I still need to supply a configured instance of my class versus just the class so I needed a reliable location where I could create it.

Comment: All I can say is that you should clear `isLoading` in `finally`.